# How to read marker info from mysql and display those markers on google map dynamically using AJAX? Timing issues

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

My app uses javascript, google maps api, php and mysql. It is supposed to get a list of markers from mysql database, dump it onto a myXML.xml file and then read this file in order to draw these markers on the map everytime the map loads.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>...</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
    ...
    //load previous markers from dbase
    **loadMarkers();**

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//loadMarkers
function **loadMarkers()**
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
        ***//alert("here1");***
            xmlDoc.load("myXML.xml");
            xmlDoc.async=false;
        ***//alert("here2");***
            //xmlDoc.onload=doNothing;

            var markerNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) 
            {
                var RowID = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("RowID");
                var LatLng = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("LatLng");
                var Type = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Type");
                alert(Type);
                //Separate Lat and Lng from LatLng
                var string = LatLng;
                var n=string.indexOf(",");
                var Lat = string.slice(1,n);
                var n2=string.indexOf(")");
                var Lng = string.slice(n+2,n2);

                //Set Marker Type
                if(Type=="hospital")
                    markerIcon='markHospital.png';
                if(Type=="airport")
                    markerIcon="airport.jpg";

                var marker3=new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng),
                    icon:markerIcon
                    //icon:'markHospital.png'
                    //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                    });

                marker3.setMap(map);

            }
        }
    }
    //xmlhttp.open("GET","addmarker.php?maidenLatLng="+maidenLatLng+"&clickID="+clickID,true);
    var queryString = "";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getmarkers.php" + queryString, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

    ...
```

The code seems to work fine but only when the two alert messages (inside **loadMarkers()**)are NOT commented out. The moment they are commented out (as they are now) then old markers do not load and are not visible.

I suspect this is timing issue of some kind. may be the myXML.xml file is not ready when the script reaches that point. So, i also set the async property of XMLHTTPRequest to false. But that didn't help either. Any idea why this script works only when the two **alert** boxes are allowed to run?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what does the Network console show for the request to myxml.xml file? also, why not return XML from getmarkers.php?

Comment: the myxml.xml file is being written fine. And as said earlier, the same code works when alert()s are called. so must be timing issue of some kind. tried delaying the script execution using setInterval() too but to no avail. And i need the .xml file separately too :)

Comment: the question is does the request fetching the xml file succeeds when there is not delay? not whether the xml file gets written successfully.

Comment: how do we check for that? sry, I'm a newbie here :)

Comment: if you have Chrome, there is a console window with Network tab in it. you can see it there. in other browsers, I am sure there are similar things. For example in Firefox you can install firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery, you could use something like [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to only load all the markers from the XML once the AJAX request had completed.

Comment: any way to achieve that without using jQuery? 

Just curious, wouldn't setting `xmlhttp.open("GET", "getmarkers.php" + queryString, true);` to **false** (near the end of the script) achieve something to the similar effect? However, i tried that too and it seems to have no effect on the execution.